# It's possible to use HTML5 validation on non-required fields?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have problem with validation on non-required field. When someone activates validation on this field it cannot be sent to the server even if field is empty. My html code looks like that:

```
<form>
    <input pattern=".{6,}" name="field" size="25" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I also use jQuery to customise validation message:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name=field]")[0].oninvalid = function () {
        this.setCustomValidity("Please enter at least 5 characters.");
        this.setCustomValidity("");
    };
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "someone activates the validation on the field"? Do you mean they inspect the element and set it themselves?

Comment: @peter novalidate flag isn't solution of my problem. I don't want completly disable validation.

Comment: This means that validation has to be disactive when user removes value from this field.

Comment: So you don't want to validate when field is empty ?

Comment: Check my answer then...should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, when you change the field again, then you setCustomValidity to empty and not in oninvalid event handler. Try this

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name=field]")[0].oninvalid = function () {
        this.setCustomValidity("Please enter at least 5 characters.");


    };

 $("input[name=field]")[0].onchange = function () {
        this.setCustomValidity("");
    };    

});
```